# How to set view to center only vertically when select annotation

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, center

Now, when I select the annotation I reposition the view to center like this:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

But how can I reposition my view to center only vertically and not horizontally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a new coordinate that has the latitude from the annotation and the current longitude

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(view.annotation.coordinate.latitude, mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
```

Set it as you were doing before

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:newCenter animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the Y of the map view but center the X should be something like this:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:[self convertPoint:CGPointMake(view.annotation.coordinate.x /* or whatever x is in the coordinate sys*/, mapView.frame.origin.y) toCoordinateFromView:mapView] animated:YES];
```

convert the point to the CLLocationCoordinate2D:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

This should be somewhat help you with your problem. Good luck.